# How to create an UIScrollView from a nib file in iOs

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, xib

I am trying to create a scrollable view in an iOS app. If I do this programmatically, everything works fine, like in:

CODE A

```
- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;

    CGRect tfRect = CGRectMake(20, 70, 240, 30);
    UILabel *tf = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:tfRect];
    tf.text = @"Some additional text!";
    [scrollView addSubview:tf];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 1000.0)
    [self setView: scrollView];
}
```

Unfortunately I have a rather complex view layout, so I designed it in a nib/xib. But, when I load that into nib into the scroll view ... it does not scroll.

CODE B

```
- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TOGPraiseController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 1000.0)
    [self setView: scrollView];
}
```

The content loads fine, but no matter which attributes of the view I change, it never ever scrolls. If I allow bouncing, I can see, that even all elements (subviews) below the bottom are there and I can drag them into view temporarily. But then they bounce back. And scroll indicators never appear.

What am I doing wrong. Which attributes do I have to set in the UIScrollView, so that scrolling is enabled. It seems that the interface editor of XCode sets some attributes, which prohibit scrolling.

Comment: Did you add the UIScrollView to your xib interface & get the IBOutlet from that ScrollView??

Comment: The UIScrollview is the main element in the xib. And I don't understand the question "& get the IBOutlet from that ScrollView" 

If I didn't do this, wouldn't I get an error when loading the nib?

Comment: You should add the ScrollView from the xib to the .m file as a property. And instead of using     UIScrollView *scrollView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TOGPraiseController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
You can use that property